# Three.js split faces from sphere

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry

I am creating an sphere geometry.

```
geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 20, 10 );
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.FlatShading, color: 0xff0000 });
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add( sphere );
```

What I want is when I click on this geometry the faces get detach like in the example below.
(*Click on the sphere button to see detached faces*)
http://www.mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/threejs/css3d/periodictable/

Comment: See, for example, http://threejs/examples/webgl_geometry_tessellation.html. But in the example, you will have to change one line so it works correctly: `uniforms.amplitude.value = 10 * Math.sin( time * 0.5 );` The program is workng, but the effect is just not visible because the change is so small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full code for the example you posted is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/9XGuK/4/

Specifically, this part of the example:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

    for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

        var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
        var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;

        var object = new THREE.Object3D();

        object.position.x = 800 * Math.cos( theta ) * Math.sin( phi );
        object.position.y = 800 * Math.sin( theta ) * Math.sin( phi );
        object.position.z = 800 * Math.cos( phi );

        vector.copy( object.position ).multiplyScalar( 2 );

        object.lookAt( vector );

        targets.sphere.push( object );

    }
```

Perhaps you can recreate this code locally to better understand how it all works and then adapt it to suit your needs.